# pgfplots axis labels for edgeworth box

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am drawing an edgeworth box which needs axes labels on all sides of the graph. Edgeworth boxes have an origin in the top right corner (as well as the bottom left) so I need axis labels that are flipped (e.g. 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1).

This is the code I tried but rather than displaying the number I want actually displays `10-1`, etc.

How could I fix this?

```
         \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
            \draw (\x cm,228.772pt) -- (\x cm,226.772pt) node[anchor=south] {10-$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
            \draw (285.465pt,\y cm) -- (283.465pt,\y cm) node[anchor=west] {8-$\y$};
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\foreach \x in {9,...,1}  \draw ({100-\x},228.772pt) -- ({100-\x} cm,226.772pt) node[anchor=south] {$\x$};`

Comment: @hpekristiansen thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {9,8,...,1}{
            \draw (9-\x,6.9) --++ (0,2mm) node[anchor=south] {\x};
        }
        \foreach \y in {7,6,...,1}{
            \draw (8.9,7-\y) --++ (2mm,0) node[anchor=west] {\y};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe better :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
            major grid style={dotted},
            axis line style={shorten >=-10pt},
            xmin=0, xmax=10,xtick={1,2,...,9},
            ymin=0, ymax=8,ytick={1,2,...,7},
        }
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=major,
            axis y line=left,
            axis x line=bottom,
            ]
            
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
            x dir=reverse,
            y dir=reverse,
            axis y line=right, grid=none,
            axis x line=top,
            ]
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```